# run arrayfire on ec2 gpu

Tags: amazon-ec2, cuda, gpu, arrayfire

Recent days we are trying to use  Amazon GPU instances.But their graphic card NVIDIA GRID K520 supports only cuda 5.5.  From installation documentation of arrayfire minimum version of cuda is 6.5.Need help to compile arrayfire with cuda 5.5.

Comment: What about that is inconsistent? It is just a simple limitation... You will have to wait for newer drivers to come out I guess.

Comment: SUre but maybe somebody succeded to compile arrayfire with cuda 5.5

Comment: Right but then your question should ask for help with compiling arrayfire for CUDA 5.5 and not about "_these_ inconsistencies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to compile ArrayFire using CUDA 5.5. In fact I was just able to do so on my MacBook Pro. All you have to do is change the CUDA_VERSION to 5.5 in the CMake options.

You should also be able to update the CUDA Toolkit on the EC2 instance. I can't think of a reason why you wouldn't be able to update the driver and install the newest CUDA Toolkit on the machine.

If you have additional questions you can find us at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/arrayfire-users

Comment: Thank you for reply i tried to get new driver for EC2 gcard but without success.There are not current support.According to arrayfire there are a lot of compilation errors if you change  CUDA_VERSION to 5.5 at list if you use last release.

Comment: Can you make a post on the google groups listed in my answer? StackOverflow is not a good platform for this type of back and forth. Make sure you post your EC2 configuration so I can recreate the errors. I will update the answer with what we find.